# In Skype, how to block "User requests your details"?

Tags: skype, privacy

In Skype, I've set my privacy settings to be as strict as possible:

[image]

However I still get a few alerts every week requesting my details. For example, a small red flag that says "5 new events" and a message: "5 Users request your details".

How can I block such messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is less a security/privacy setting than a bugging notice. All you need to do is just switch off the option to have Skype let you know.

> Tools > Options > Notifications > Notification settings

Uncheck "requests my contact details" and save. You'll now not be bothered about this alert everytime someone wants your details.

[image: Skype alerts]